# C# Removing separator characters from quoted strings

Tags: c#, regex, string, text-files

I'm writing a program that has to remove separator characters from quoted strings in text files.

For example:

```
"Hello, my name is world"
```

Has to be:

```
"Hello my name is world"
```

This sounds quite easy at first (I thought it would be), but you need to detect when the quote starts, when the quote ends, then search that specific string for separator characters. How?

I've experimented with some Regexs but I just keep getting myself confused!

Any ideas? Even just something to get the ball rolling, I'm just completely stumped.

Comment: Are you removing the commas for the sake of making it parse-able for  CSV? If so, there are RegEx's available to pull the tokens out that follow the "standard" CSV format. If not, ignore this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string pattern = "\"([^\"]+)\"";
value = Regex.Match(textToSearch, pattern).Value;

string[] removalCharacters = {",",";"}; //or any other characters
foreach (string character in removalCharacters)
{
    value = value.Replace(character, "");
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful when using the dot in Regex though; in .Net it is greedy (meaning it will start at the first open quote and end at the last close quote). Therefore, you would lose all commas and semis in between. You could, however, do this: `string pattern = "\"([^\"]+)\"";` which will start at open quote and stop when it finds another quote.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the example. I'm fairly new to regular expressions so thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

why not try and do it with Linq ?

```
var x = @" this is a great whatever ""Hello, my name is world"" and all that";

var result = string.Join(@"""", x.Split('"').
Select((val, index) => index%2 == 1 ? 
val.Replace(",", "") : val).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex pattern with a look-ahead the pattern would be: `"\"(?=[^\"]+,)[^\"]+\""`

The `\"` matches the opening double-quote. The look-ahead `(?=[^\"]+,)` will try to match a comma within the quoted text. Next we match the rest of the string as long as it's not a double-quote `[^\"]+`, then we match the closing double-quote `\"`.

Using `Regex.Replace` allows for a compact approach to altering the result and removing the unwanted commas.

```
string input = "\"Hello, my name, is world\"";
string pattern = "\"(?=[^\"]+,)[^\"]+\"";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => m.Value.Replace(",", ""));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to write is called a "lexer" (or alternatively a "tokenizer"), that reads the input character by character and breaks it up into tokens. That's generally how parsing in a compiler works (as a first step). A lexer will break text up into a stream of tokens (string literal, identifer, "(", etc). The parser then takes those tokens, and uses them to produce a parse tree.

In your case, you only need a lexer. You will have 2 types of tokens "quoted strings", and "everything else".

You then just need to write code to break the input up into tokens. By default something is an "everything else" token. A string token starts when you see a ", and ends when you see the next ". If you are reading source code you may have to deal with things like \" or "" as special cases.

Once you have done that, then you can just iterate over the tokens and do what ever processing you need on the "string" tokens.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you have some long text with a lot of quotes inside? I would make a method that does something like this:

1. Run thought the string until you encounter the first "
2. Then take the substring up till the next ", and do a str.Replace(",","") and also replace any other characters that you want to replace.
3. Then go without replacing until you encounter the next " and continue until the end.

**EDIT**

I just got a better idea. What about this:

```
  string mycompletestring = "This is a string\"containing, a quote\"and some more text";
  string[] splitstring = mycompletestring.Split('"');
  for (int i = 1; i < splitstring.Length; i += 2) {
    splitstring[i] = splitstring[i].Replace(",", "");
  }
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (string s in splitstring) {
    builder.Append(s + '"');
  }
  mycompletestring = builder.ToString().Substring(0, builder.ToString().Length - 1);
```

I think there should be a better way of combining the string into one with a " between them at the end, but I don't know any better ones, so feel free to suggest a good method here :)

Comment: This does sound like what I need to do.. I'm actually reading in files using a StreamReader, but I'm reading in line by line using ReadLine(). Should I just do this to every line?

Comment: Why not read the entire file in one go, use my approach inside the **EDIT** part of the post, and then write it to the file again also? Doing it line by line will get messed up if the quote start on one line, and end on another line (at least with my implementation, but of course you can fix that also if you like if you make your own implementation)

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily want to do this to every line, in case a quote spans more than one line. You would want to ReadToEnd to get all of the text at once, then do what is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar in an application I use to translate flat files.  This is the approach I took:  (just a copy/paste from my application)

```
        protected virtual string[] delimitCVSBuffer(string inputBuffer) {
        List<string> output       = new List<string>();
        bool insideQuotes         = false;
        StringBuilder fieldBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in inputBuffer) {
            if (c == FieldDelimiter && !insideQuotes) {
                output.Add(fieldBuffer.Remove(0, 1).Remove(fieldBuffer.Length - 1, 1).ToString().Trim());
                fieldBuffer.Clear();
                continue;
            } else if (c == '\"')
                insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
            fieldBuffer.Append(c);
        }
        output.Add(fieldBuffer.Remove(0, 1).Remove(fieldBuffer.Length - 1, 1).ToString().Trim());
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: A little more background here... The Input to this would be a bunch of comma delimited strings with quotes around them.  Like:  "abc123","123abc","blah", and it would return a string array of the text inside the quotes.  From there, you can do any character replacements you need.  The "FieldDelimiter" could be any character you specify, but in this case it is a comma.

Comment: If that is what you want to do, why not just use string.Split('"'), and return all the strings with even index?

Comment: It's meant to be configurable, so I can pass it the delimiter of my choice.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see what you're saying now...I guess I went a long way around to do something simple.  thanks for the suggestion! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a bit wacky, but it works.

So first off you split your string up into parts, based on the `"` character:

```
string msg = "this string should have a comma here,\"but, there should be no comma in this bit\", and there should be a comma back at that and";

var parts = msg.Split('"');
```

then you need to join the string back together on the `"` character, after removing each comma in every other part:

```
string result = string.Join("\"", RemoveCommaFromEveryOther(parts));
```

The removal function looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> RemoveCommaFromEveryOther(IEnumerable<string> parts)
{
    using (var partenum = parts.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool replace = false;
        while (partenum.MoveNext())
        {
            if(replace)
            {
                yield return partenum.Current.Replace(",","");
                replace = false;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return partenum.Current;
                replace = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The does require that you include a using directive for `System.Collections.Generic`.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this:
Lok at the functions `string.Split()` and `string.IndexOfAny()`

You can use string.Split(new char[] {',',' '}, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries) to slipt the phrase into words, then use the `StringBuilder` class to put the words together.

Calling `string.Replace("[char to remove goes here]"',"")` multiple times with each char you want to remove will also work.

EDIT:

Call `string.Split(new char[] {'\"'}, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries)` to obtain an array of the strings that are between quotes ( " ) then call `Replace` on each of them, then put the strings together with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Hint: You can write string.Split(new char[] {'\"'} as string.Split('"'}

Comment: your edit won't work, as that is the same as calling `thestring.replace("\", "")`, you need to replace the commas in every other string, and the `StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries` means that you get the wrong order for the string if your string starts with a quote and lose any empty quote blocks from the text. -1