# Remove single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove single quotes from string as per below example.

> Input : 'I am a 'microsoft' developer'
>
> OutPut : I am a microsoft developer

---

> Input : 'Let's play a 'big' Game'
>
> OutPut : Let's play a big Game

---

> Input : 'James' Computer'
>
> OutPut : James' Computer

Please suggest best approach to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: In the *second* example: why you spare `'` in the `Let's`?

Comment: What happens with `'I'm innocent'`?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4215595/4517421 , you should find the solution.

Comment: What should be the output for `doubled'' apostroph`? Note, that `'` is doubled; `tripled ''' one`?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko this is a business need.

Comment: @Mahesh: could you, please, provide *all exceptions* (business needs) where apostrophes should be preserved *intact*?

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko As of now below three [1] 'I am a 'microsoft' developer' [2]  'Let's play a 'big' Game' [3] James' computer

Comment: Another idea using [regex and two time replace at ideone](https://ideone.com/e60SDc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you go

```
string Input1 = "'I am a 'microsoft' developer'";
string Input2 = "'Let's play a 'big' Game'";

string Result1 = string.Join(" ", Input1.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Trim('\'')));
string Result2 = string.Join(" ", Input2.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Trim('\'')));
```

i remove every `'` which is at the beginning or the end of a word

**Update:**

as Oliver Nicholls pointed out, there should be some special cases like `James'`. In this case the `'` should be kept. Example:

```
string Input3 = "'Let's play James' Game'";
string Result3 = string.Join(" ", Input3.Split(' ').Select(x => !x.EndsWith("s'")?x.Trim('\''): x.TrimStart('\'')));
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you could say something like "James' computer", in which case this wouldn't work. Not trying to aimlessly criticise your answer of course. I think the requirements need to be more specific.

Comment: that's a good point, you can check if the word ends with `s'` and in this case only trim at start of the word . i've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string origin = "Let's play a 'big' Game";
            string replaced = origin.Replace(" \'", " ").Replace("\' ", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove quotes which are not inside words:

```
string t = "'Let's play a 'big' Game'";
string[] words = t.Split(' ');
string res = "";
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    res += words[i].Trim('\'') + "";

    if ((words.Length - 1) > i)
    {
        res += " ";
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(res);
```